# Interface specific firewalld rules

Tags: firewalld

I have Linux VM with multiple NICs configured, eth0 and eth1. Now I want SSH to be enabled on both the NICs and HTTPS only on eth0. I have made drop zone as default to drop all traffic other than it.

But if I add this configuration in public zone as following

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client https ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Then https and ssh will be enabled on both NICs or any one NIC. Is there any way to manage NIC-service relation ?

Answer (score 3):

Firewalld maps rules to interfaces using the idea of "zones". You add a service to a zone (`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent`) and this service will be permitted on all interfaces that are members of that zone.

If you want different rules for different interfaces, you will need to create separate zones.

[This article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/understanding-firewalld-multi-zone-configurations) from Linux Journal is a good resource on the topic, and includes example of multi-zone configurations.

For example:

- Remove eth1 from your `public` zone and move it to the `internal` zone:

  ```
  firewall-cmd --zone=internal --change-interface=eth1 --permanent
  ```
- Allow `ssh` on the `internal` zone:

  ```
  firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-service=ssh --permanent
  ```
- Reload the firewall configuration:

  ```
  firewall-cmd --reload
  ```

Then add and remove services as necessary to your `internal` and `public` zones to reach your desired configuration.

---

Alternatively, if you have a relatively simple firewall configuration you could just get rid of `firewalld` and manually write your `iptables` rules.

Comment: Thanks larsks. Looks like I need to create custom zone for each interface.